# get_list_or_404 with multiple filters in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Model name Student:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade)
    hr_teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='hr_students')
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s (G-%s, %s)' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.grade.short_name, self.unique_id)

    def hr_teacher_absent(self):
        return self.hr_teacher.groups.filter(name='Absent Teachers').count() > 0

    def hr_booking(self):
        return self.booking_set.filter(teacher=self.hr_teacher,status__uses_space=True)

    def has_booking(self):
        return bool(self.hr_booking())

    def hr_booking_for_event(self, ptc_event):
        return self.hr_booking().filter(period__ptc_event=ptc_event)

    def has_booking_for_event(self, ptc_event):
        return bool(self.hr_booking_for_event(ptc_event))

    def delete_all_bad_bookings(self):
        bad_bookings = self.booking_set.exclude(teacher=self.hr_teacher).delete()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['grade','last_name','first_name']
```

Each Student has a Home Room Teacher which is a User in Group name 'Teachers' (those are default user, group defined in django's admin). I'm trying to get a list of user in group Teachers who has at least 1 Students. Here's my code:

```
teacher_list_db = get_object_or_404(Group, name="Teachers").user_set.annotate(num_students=Count('hr_students')).filter(num_students__gt=0).order_by("last_name","first_name")
```

and it returned an empty array.

I read the django documentation and found out this method:

```
get_list_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs)
```

I tried and got stuck here:

```
teacher_list_db = get_list_or_404(User.objects.order_by('last_name', 'first_name'), groups__name='Teachers')
```

I don't know how to do with the annotation part which counts the number of students has the same teacher!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've just figured it out:

```
teachers_list_db = get_list_or_404(User.objects.order_by('last_name', 'first_name'), groups__name='Teachers')
if teachers_list_db:
    teachers_list = []
    for teacher in teacher_list_db:
        if teacher.hr_students.all().count() >= 0:
            teachers_list.append(teacher)
```

**teachers_list** is the list I need.

Yay! Django is wonderful!!! \m/

Comment: If your solution is wrong, could you please un-accept the answer? I know this post is old but I ended up here and spent a fair amount of time breaking down what you did before seeing your comment.